# Uncaught ReferenceError and processForm is not defined

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

How can i call a form from out side the form, I have a form in angular, i am using bootstrap 
Here is a snippet , a form with ngubmit and for the save of design i try to call from outside , please how do i go about it

```
   <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="btn btn-light"
               type="submit"
               title="Save department"
               data-toggle="tooltip"
               data-placement="bottom">
              <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
              <span class="d-none d-sm-inline" *** this is where i tried to call the form**** onclick="processForm()">Save</span></a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

    </header>
    <section id="department">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
    ****this is the begining of the form 
                <form  (ngSubmit)="processForm()"    id="editFormTruck" >

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label"
                           ngFor="truckCode">Truck code</label>
                    <input type="text" name="truckCode"  class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="truck.truckCode">
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label"
                          ngFor="purchasedDate">purchased Date</label>
                    <input type="date" name="purchaseDate" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="truck.purchasedDate" useValueAsDate>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label"
                           ngFor="truck.description">Description</label>
                    <input type="text" name="description" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="truck.description">
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Is all of this html shown in your component template? Not asking if there is more HTML, just making sure what you have shown is all in the same component and not somehow spread across multiple components

Comment: Are you trying to use Angular here? `onclick="processForm()"` If so, you'll need syntax like this: `(click)="processForm()"`

Comment: yes its all in the same component and you say on my form i should use this or on the save section ( my save button)

Comment: Your save button. Using `onclick` uses the native JS click handler behavior but you instead want Angular to wire it up, so use the `(click)` syntax.

Comment: what about also connecting them with id

Comment: in  form i did this form  (ngSubmit)="processForm().valid"  id="editFormTruck"

Comment: then save button   ngForm="editFormTruck"
           (click)="processForm()"

Comment: is this right ?

Comment: When you click save, are you just trying to submit your form?

Comment: yes just submit the for and it still doesnt work

Comment: in my console im getting null response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to submit your form manually, you can get a reference to your form and manually trigger an emit on the `ngSubmit`. I put together a [simple Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/ehKPRSoqvymWBPPMyM4V?p=preview) doing it.

```html
<span class="d-none d-sm-inline" (click)="form.ngSubmit.emit()">Save</span>

...

<form #form (ngSubmit)="processForm()" ...>...</form>
```

Comment: I have two urls , this is a different question but would help? curl -v localhost:8088/orders/
      // curl -v  http://localhost:8088/orders?start=2007-01-01&end=2008-01-01
     */ as you see they orders and orders filter, i want to get a list of order by default in my angular app and also have the choice of filtering by dates , how would that go please?

Comment: Please create a new question and somebody will help you out with it. It is not appropriate to ask for help this way.